# Query Results caching using Java : Any better Approaches?

Tags: java

I have a class ClassA which calls another class(DAO) to fetch the query results. In a specific business scenario,

ClassA invokes the DAO with queryparameters about 20,000 times. 
Out of this, about 10,000 times ClassA sends same set of query parameters to DAO. Obviously Resultset will be the same and can be cached.

The following is the code I implemented.

```
Class A

{

.
.
.
.

Map<String, CachData> cachDataMap= new HashMap<String, CachData>();

priavate void getQueryResults(String queryParam)    
{

try {


            Set<String> cacheSet = cachDataMap.keySet();
            CachData cachData = null;
            if(!cacheSet.contains(queryParam))
            {
                dao.getResuslts((queryParam)));
                cachData = new CachData();
                cachData.setResult0(__getStringResult(0));
                cachData.setResult1(__getStringResult(1));
                cachData.setResult2(__getStringResult(2));
                cachData.setResult3(__getStringResult(3));
                cachData.setResult4(__getStringResult(4));
                cachData.setResult5(__getStringResult(5));
                cachDataMap.put(queryParam, cachData);
            }else
            {
                cachData = cachDataMap.get(queryParam);
            }



        } catch(Exception e) {
            //handle here
        }


}
```

Do we have anyother better solution other than using any framework? A better datastructure or better method.. For good performance?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).

Whatever you do don't use a Map as your interface for a cache. A good cache interface would allow the implementation to do cleanup of the cache. The Map contract won't allow this.

Depending on the implementation, cleanup can be based on time in the cache, or based on usage statistics, or memory availability, ...

The Map approach you're using here seems prone to go out of memory over a longer period of usage.

Comment: Thanks bowmore. Assume I don't want use any framework as I said in my question, can you see any improvement area on the above code? If not Set what else could be a better choice in the above code? Any idea?

Comment: I think the key is to have a Cache interface, that allows basic put and get operations, but doesn't carry all the bagage of the Set interface. You can roll your own cache implementation (which uses a Set behind the scenes), but you'll always have the option of switching to a framework implementation, or an improved implementation of your own. But in the case of a DAO, I would definitely look into a mechanism to clean up the cache intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Table from [guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and use [ehCache](http://ehcache.org/) to save the object as it is with the key being the query.